Regarding Salat during sunrise
Assalamu Alaikum. I woke up before sunrise but unfortunately by the time I had done my wudu the sun was already rising. So during sunrise should I pray the Farz first or Sunnah? Can I pray the Sunnah during sunrise or should I pray the Farz and pray the Sunnah after the sunrise?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

wa alaikom slam wa rahmatullah wa barakatu,
you should first pray the Fajr Farz (obligatory prayer) as it takes precedence. Fajr Farz must be prayed even if its sunrise,Do not pray when the sun is rising or when it is setting."
(Sahih Muslim) is referring to voluntary prayer not obbligatory
After performing the Fajr Farz, you should then wait for the sun to fully rise, and once the sun has risen completely (usually about 15–20 minutes after sunrise), you can perform the Sunnah prayers for Fajr (the two rak'ahs that are generally prayed before the Fajr Farz).
